# Does Kudo's transgression theorem still hold when the coefficient is ℤ/pⁿℤ?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I am trying to compute a Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence with coefficient $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is an odd prime, and Kudo's transgression theorem looks like a good tool for me to obtain the $E_\infty$-page. However, all the versions of Kudo's Theorem I can find are given under coefficient $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**My question is:** I understand that we can extend the coefficient to some field $K$ of characteristic $p$, but what if the coefficient is $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is an odd prime?

As a reference, here is a statement of the Kudo's transgression theorem provided by *"[A user's guide to spectral sequences](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511626289)"*, John McCleary, where the coefficient is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$:

**Theorem**  *If a class $x$ in $E^{0, 2k}_2\cong H^{2k}(F; \mathbb{F}_p)$ is transgressive and $x$ transgresses to the element represented by $y$ in $E^{2k+1, 0}_2\cong H^{2k+1}(B; \mathbb{F}_p)$, then $P^kx = x^p$ and $y\otimes x^{p-1}$ are also transgressive with $d_{2pk+1}(x^p) = P^ky$ and $d_{2(p-1)k+1}(y\otimes x^{p-1}) = -\beta P^k y$. (Here $\beta$ denotes the mod $p$ Bockstein in the Steenrod algebra $\mathcal{A}_p$.)*

Comment: @LSpice out of curiosity, why did you insert unicode in the title, rather than standard latex?

Comment: @YCor, some people prefer not to have LaTeX in their titles, so I respect that when editing.

Comment: @YuxiangYao What is the meaning of $P^k$? I only know about this operation mod p.  Is there a standard generalization to $p^2$?

Comment: @John Wiltshire-Gordon This is the notation for the operator $P^k: H^{*}(-; \mathbb{F}_p)\to H^{*, 2k(p-1)}(-; \mathbb{F}_p)$, which is a generator of mod $p$ Steenrod algebra. But I wonder if we can somehow generalize the Kudo's transgression theorem to coefficient $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ case. I am not pretty sure if there is a reasonably good application, but I am trying to compute the $E_\infty$ page of the Lydon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence induced from the exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ when I read McCleary's book.

Comment: @YCor Sorry this is the first time I asked a question on this whole platform, so I am not quite sure if LaTeX works in the title yet. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the editing.